# Arduino compile error of U8glib library on Win 10

Tags: arduino, u8glib

Trying to compile Marlin firmware with U8Glib LCD library to upload to my ATMega 2560, this is the error I got:

> Using library U8glib at version 1.19.1 in folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\U8glib  fork/exec C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-gcc.exe: The filename or
>   extension is too long. Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Mega
>   or Mega 2560.

I have successfully compiled and uploaded before, this is happening only after setting a change to incorporate U8Glib. I have tried installing it manually, from the IDE, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the same thing and got this same error.
Apparently this is a Windows file system problem.

I solved this by compiling/uploading using another computer running Ubuntu 14.04

Microsoft support says there is a hotfix for this problem and it should be present in Windows 7 service pack1.
I have W7 SP1 and problem persists... So back to Ubuntu then.. :)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. I have Win 10. As I needed this I had to circumvent the problem using the Repetier firmware, which did not crash during compile - using the same U8glib.